# milliseconds until next 5th second

Tags: java

So I want to do some monitoring and I want it to be on every fifth minute, so for example if the application starts at 1:47 monitor everything until 1:50 and then reset. I currently have this working for hour but I need to cut it down to every fifth minute and I'm having a little trouble coming up with the math.

I get all of the current time information

```
  Calendar currentCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
  long currentTimeInMillis = currentCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
  int hr = currentCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
  int min = currentCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
  int sec = currentCalendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
  int millis = currentCalendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
```

Now I need to find the next fifth minute, for hour I have this which works.

```
  millisUntilNextHour = currentTimeInMillis + ((60L - min) * SECONDS_IN_MINUTE * 1000L) + ((60 - sec) * 1000L) + (1000L - millis);
```

Can anybody think of a way similar to above to get the milliseconds to the closest fifth minute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every fifth minute is `5 minutes * 60 seconds/minute * 1000 millisecond/second = 300,000 milliseconds`.

Try this then:

```
millisUntilNextHour = (min*60*1000 + sec*1000 + millis + 299999)/300000*300000 - (min*60*1000 + sec*1000 + millis)
```

The `+299999)/300000*300000` rounds up to the nearest 300,000. Then you get the difference between that and the current millisecond to find out how many milliseconds you are away from it.

Comment: I chose this as the correct answer because it goes the best with the rest of my code and it's also the fastest. I don't have to recreate any objects with this, whereas I would've had to if I needed to reuse the Calendar instance. Thanks everybody.

Comment: @Ryan: Please check my math and test it out. I wrote it rather quickly so there very well could be careless mistakes. However the general method is correct.

Comment: Yeah I have tested it before I answered, works like a charm. I only need this for the first pass of when the application starts, after that I have a timer that kicks off an update every 300,000 milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

Using the same approach as described in the question:

```
 Calendar currentCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
 int min = currentCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
 currentCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 5 * (min / 5 + 1));
 currentCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
 currentCalendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

 millisUntilNextHour = currentCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

**Update:**
Reverted to my initial variant. It works as a charm. Lenient calendar (currentCalendar is lenient) works perfectly as expected when setting as minutes value greater than 60. From javadoc:

```
/**
 * With lenient interpretation, a date such as "February 942, 1996" will be
 * treated as being equivalent to the 941st day after February 1, 1996.
 * With strict (non-lenient) interpretation, such dates will cause an exception to be
 * thrown. The default is lenient.
 */
```

Comment: Yes, it's an almost correct solution, guaranteed to fail eventually.

Comment: Who cares, will fail in 42 minutes only :). works 91% of time

Comment: @Edwin Buck Ha, actually initial variant was correct, reverting to that.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/), which can handle this sort of thing easily. For the above you could specify a cron-type expression.

It may seem a bit heavyweight for your initial requirements but it's scaleable so it'll handle any future requirements.

Comment: It's not a direct complaint, but any time related question quickly receives a use "X" answer instead of a "here's how you do this with X answer".  While it may be correct to direct a person to a new toolkit, not providing an answer to the question under the new toolkit still leaves the question unanswered.

Comment: The application we are building is going to be pretty heavy and is meant to be as quick as possible, we thought about using Quartz but we did find it to be a bit too heavy for our app.

Answer (score 0):

Add five minutes to the current time, then set the seconds and millis to zero.

Note that the important thing is to use the `.add(field, amount)` method, as it will roll correctly into the next hour, etc. (including daylight savings, etc).

```
 Calendar currentCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
 // store off the milliseconds from the epoch
 int startTime = currentCalendar.getTime().getTime();
 currentCalendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
 currentCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
 currentCalendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

 // calculate the milliseconds difference.
 int difference = currentCalendar.getTime().getTime() - startTime;
 System.out.println("The number of milliseconds till " + currentCalendar.getTime() + " is " + startTime);
```